# How to switch column inside proof in multicols?

Tags: equations, multicol

Here, I write my documents in the following template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{<listofpackages>}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
blablabla
\begin{proof}
blablablabla
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
\end{proof}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And the result is as I provided in the picture below. The problem is, equation (21) is overfull and hence I want it to be exactly looks like equation (20). I tried to use `[]` to switch the column, but it doesn't work. I guess it's because the `[]` is inside the proof environment. Is there a fix to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Equation (21) would not appear to be important enough to warrant interrupting the document's two-column layout. I suggest you employ a `multline` environment instead of an `equation` environment to typeset it across two lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol,geometry}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{20} % just for this example

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem 2] 
\dots

Then, prove (18). It follows from 
\textbf{Proposition 2}~(\textit{i}) that
\begin{multline}
f_{\gamma^*}^*(x) 
  = \max_{u\in\mathcal{U}} \bigl\{ \ell(u) - c_0 \\
  -\bigl[ h(x) + \gamma^* - c_0\mu 
  - \mu f_{\gamma^*}^*(x+1)\bigr] u \bigr\}
\end{multline}
\dots
\end{proof}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```